# How to use .not selector in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two divs `task1` and `task2`. In these tasks, there are panels with names.
In `task2`, I have a duplicate (Greg). This duplicate have also a duplicate class.
How can I search for a name and skip the duplicates? I tried to use the `:not()` selector but this didn't work.

My example:

```
 <div class="container">
  <div id="department-task1">
    <div class="panel">
      <p class="panel-name">Jeff</p>
    </div>
    <div class="panel">
       <p class="panel-name">Greg</p>
    </div>
    <div class="panel">
       <p class="panel-name">Peter</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <br>

  <div id="department-task2">
    <div class="panel">
       <p class="panel-name">Mary</p>
    </div>
    <div class="panel">
       <p class="panel-name">John</p>
    </div>
    <div class="panel duplicate">
       <p class="panel-name">Greg</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    function isNamePresent($name) {

        $leader = $(".container :not(.duplicate) .name:contains(" + $name + ")"); 

        return $leader.css("color", "blue");

    }

    isNamePresent("Greg");

});
```

Comment: if u want to find duplicates, why not just search for the class 'duplicate'; why are u trying to skip it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this: `$leader = $(".container .panel:not(.duplicate) .panel-name:contains(" + $name + ")");`

First off you have no class `name`, you have `panel-name`

Second, use `.panel:not(.duplicate)` to make sure it looks for an element with the class `panel` that don't have another class `duplicate`

**Working demo**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  function isNamePresent($name) {
    $leader = $(".container .panel:not(.duplicate) .panel-name:contains(" + $name + ")");
    return $leader.css("color", "blue");

  }

  isNamePresent("Greg");

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div id="department-task1">
    <div class="panel">
      <p class="panel-name">Jeff</p>
    </div>
    <div class="panel">
      <p class="panel-name">Greg</p>
    </div>
    <div class="panel">
      <p class="panel-name">Peter</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <br>

  <div id="department-task2">
    <div class="panel">
      <p class="panel-name">Mary</p>
    </div>
    <div class="panel">
      <p class="panel-name">John</p>
    </div>
    <div class="panel duplicate">
      <p class="panel-name">Greg</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you its working. I edited it several times and forgot to update my question. And thats why i have panel-name as a class.

Comment: @GregOstry No problem, happy to help

Comment: This is the correct answer. Note that :not is only a CSS pseudo selector, which needs a true selector like an id or class ( in this case .panel). Also may I suggest to use "var $leader" instead of $leader. I think local scoping is wat you want here.